# How to extract the list of text between the pattern using RegEx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, text-extraction

I have text like:

```
05/06/21 05/06/21 Margin Div/Int - Income ACTIVISION BLIZZARD INC

COM
Payable: 05/06/2021
QUALIFIED DIVIDENDS 23.50 

ATVI - 0.00 23.50 (9,425.77)

05/13/21 05/13/21 Margin Div/Int - Income APPLE INC
COM
Payable: 05/13/2021
QUALIFIED DIVIDENDS 6.16 

AAPL - 0.00 6.16 (9,419.61)

05/28/21 05/28/21 Margin Div/Int - Income STARBUCKS CORP
COM
Payable: 05/28/2021
QUALIFIED DIVIDENDS 18.00 

SBUX - 0.00 18.00 (9,401.61)

05/28/21 05/28/21 Margin Div/Int - Expense MARGIN INTEREST CHARGE
Payable: 05/28/2021 

 - - 0.00 (73.03) (9,474.64)
```

I want to extract individual records, such as:

```
05/06/21 05/06/21 Margin Div/Int - Income ACTIVISION BLIZZARD INC

COM
Payable: 05/06/2021
QUALIFIED DIVIDENDS 23.50 

ATVI - 0.00 23.50 (9,425.77)
```

and

```
05/13/21 05/13/21 Margin Div/Int - Income APPLE INC
COM
Payable: 05/13/2021
QUALIFIED DIVIDENDS 6.16 

AAPL - 0.00 6.16 (9,419.61)
```

and

```
05/28/21 05/28/21 Margin Div/Int - Expense MARGIN INTEREST CHARGE
Payable: 05/28/2021 

 - - 0.00 (73.03) (9,474.64)
```

Here the pattern of each record should start with date`(\d+/\d+/\d)` and end with `(\n\n\d+/\d+/\d)`

I have tried like `(re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/\d(.*?)\n\n\d+/\d+/\d+',a))`. But it doesn't works as expected

Comment: You have mentioned "ends with `(\n\n\d+/\d+/\d)`", but your expected output ends with `\n\n`. Which is correct?

Comment: Please show the source text in code blocks and with the newlines as actual newlines, not `\n`, as that is far easier to visually parse (we are not computers!). Likewise, please give *one* example of a segment of the input you want to extract as an individual item.

Comment: Updated @Inigo...!

Comment: @SreeKumar, there is chance of having date in the middle that's why I mentioned it should end with '\n\n\d+/\d+/\d'

Comment: @codingIsInteresting thanks. I took it one step further. This is much easier for people to read/understand/see/parse/work with :)

Comment: What is the *rule* for determining where a block ends? Can we say it is a non-empty line preceding zero or more empty lines followed by a line beginning with the two dates or the end of the string?

Comment: Yes, the list entry starts with 2 dates and ends on \n\n\d+/\d+/\d+. We should extract before the \n\n. @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match

```
.+?(?=\s*(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} ){2}|$)
```

with 'g' ("global") and 's' ("single line" or "dot-all") flags set. 's' causes periods to match all characters, including line terminators.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQOKmE/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
.+?                        # match one or more chars, lazily
(?=                        # begin a positive lookahead
  \s*                      # match zero or more whitespaces
  (?:                      # begin a non-capture group 
    \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}[ ] # match a date string followed by a space
  ){2}                     # end the non-capture group and execute it twice
|                          # or
  $                        # match the end of the string
)                          # end positive lookahead
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as base and make changes to get to the exact one you need:

```
\d+\/\d+\/\d+(.*?)\\n\\n(\s+\d+\/\d+\/\d+|$)
```

You can try it in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YBXfB1/1/).

The changes I have made are these:

- `\n` becomes `\\n`.
- There is a space between `\n\n` and the dates in the sample text. I have added that in the regex.
- The year part of the date in the regex was missing `+`. I have added that
- The last part in the sample doesn't contain a date at the end. That check has been included.

Comment: I'm not getting last value and also not extracting completed data it's skips the date

Comment: I need last part also @Sree Kumar

Comment: @codingIsInteresting I made an edit to the pattern for that. Guess tyou didn't notice that.

Comment: I have checked that too. Sorry, that doesn't work

Comment: Please check the output format. Every list should starts with 2 dates and should end with \n\n. Minor changes in the regex is required @Sree Kumar

Answer (score 1):

You can match a date like pattern at the start of the string, and repeat all lines that do not start with matching a date like pattern.

```
^\d+/\d+/\d+ .*(?:\n(?!^\d+/\d+/\d+ ).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+/\d+/\d+`  Match a date like pattern and a space
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!^\d+/\d+/\d+ ).*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with a date like pattern
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zktiJX/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pK9NY8).

Use can use re.findall to get all the matches:

```
import re

pattern = r"^\d+/\d+/\d+ .*(?:\n(?!^\d+/\d+/\d+ ).*)*"
 
s = ("05/06/21 05/06/21 Margin Div/Int - Income ACTIVISION BLIZZARD INC\n\n....")
 
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```